# Solve $y^2 = x^4 +x + 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Solve the following equation in $\mathbb{Z}$:

$$y^2 = x^4 +x + 2 $$

I think I need a good estimation, but I don't see how to get that... 
I obviously see that $(1,\pm2)$ does work but how do I solve it for all $\mathbb{Z}$?

Is it smart to estimate or to try to factorize? I see that $y$ must always be even so that will work out fine I guess, but how can one make a bound for $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Treat the cases $x\gt 0$ and $x\lt 0$ separately.

Let $x\gt 0$ be an integer. Use the fact that the smallest square bigger than $x^4$ is $(x^2+1)^2$, which is $x^4+2x^2+1$.

Let $x\lt 0$.  The biggest square smaller than $x^4$ is $x^4-2x^2+1$.

To continue, suppose that $x\gt 0$. Then $x^4\lt x^4+x+2\le x^4+2x^2+1$, with equality only when $x=1$.

Comment: how does one know these squares are the smalles/biggest compare to $x^4$....?

Comment: Let $a$ be positive. The next square after $a^2$ is $(a+1)^2$. For example, the next square after $7^2$ is $8^2$.

Comment: thank you very much sir :)

Comment: You are welcome. The analysis will quickly show that the only possibilities are $x=1$ and $x=-1$. They work.  The corresponding $y$ are, respectively, $\pm 2$ and $\pm 1$.